# How is the invariance of $ds^2$ in a coordinate change defined?

Tags: metric-spaces, tensors, invariance

I will show my question with the help of an exercise I stumbled upon recently because I think it will illustrate my problem more clearly. I'm simplifying the exercise by just showing the steps and not the actual problem because it is just for illustration purposes.

We start in the cartesian coordinate system, then there is a coordinate change.

$x\rightarrow v, x =e^v -1 \Rightarrow dx = e^vdv, dx^2 = e^{2v}dv^2 $
$y \rightarrow w, y = w \Rightarrow dy = dw, dy^2= dw^2$

For a point P(4,3) in (x,y):
$v = ln(x+1) = ln(5) = 1.6 $ and $ w = y = 3$
$P(4,3) \rightarrow P'(1.6,3)$

The distance to the point P now has to be calculated.

In the (x,y) coordinates:
$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 = 4^2 + 3^2 = 16 + 9 = 25$

In the (v,w) coordinates:
$ds^2 = e^{2v}dv^2 + dw^2 = e^{2*1.6}*1.6^2 + 3^2 = 71.8$

Isn't $ds^2$ supposed to be invariant following $ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$ ? The metric tensor has changed because of the coordinate change, and therefore the value of $ds^2$ has changed. Is that right ? If so, then in what way is $ds^2$ invariant ?

Comment: Briefly: 1. We do (formally) have $dx^2 + dy^2 = ds^2 = e^{2v}\, dv^2 + dw^2$. 2. Distance in the $(v,w)$ coordinates is not given by the Pythagorean theorem. Instead you'd have to find a geodesic between two points and integrate its arc length element. Strictly speaking, the same is true of $(x,y)$ coordinates, but because the components are constant the arc length integral gives the Pythagorean distance.

Comment: So, the fact that the value of $ds^2$ changes between the two systems is normal right ? Its invariance is then therefore not defined by its value but by the way it is calculated (i. e. finding the geodesic and integrating the arc length element) ?